# Chaplin was a composer too?

Tags: soundtrack, charlie-chaplin, limelight

I was watching *Limelight* tonight and I noticed that Charlie Chaplin is credited as "Music". Does that mean he actually composed the music or did he just select it? Was he a composer as well as an actor?

Comment: Yes, he scored many of his films. AFAIK this is a well known fact and is discussed in detail [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Chaplin#Composing). Where he's introduced as "actor, filmmaker, and composer" in his entry's first line.

Answer (score 1):

As Walt said in the comments, Chaplin composed for many of his pictures. [This article](https://www.charliechaplin.com/en/articles/205-Chaplin-as-a-Composer) claims that he employed more formally trained musicians to arrange and orchestrate some of his scores, but he composed the melodies.